# SendKeys clashing with Windows Forms Application buttons

Tags: c#, windows, forms, sendkeys

I've recently made this small Windows Forms Application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Spammer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread t1;
        int delay, y = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            t1 = new Thread(send);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            delay = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            t1.Start();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            y = 0;
        }
        private void send()
        {
            while (y == 1)
            {
                String textt = textBox1.Text;
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
                SendKeys.SendWait(textt);
            }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now, it looks like this:

It has a Delay textbox, a Text to Send textbox, and 2 buttons: Start and Stop.

Now, I've tried running it and setting the delay to 1000ms.

When I press the "Stop" button, it perfectly stops and no more messages are sent.

But when I input in the delay very small delays like 100ms, for example, pressing "Stop" doesn't do anything.
It's even kind of hard to click it, and even when I click it doesn't stop sending the messages.

Why is this? And can I solve it somehow?

Comment: That's because putting the form in wait mode causes it to disregard input for the duration. To a human, 100ms is putting it into wait mode almost all the time.

Comment: Well, sure, it isn't easy to switch to another window so the keystrokes end up in the right place.  And back to click the Stop button.  All within 100 milliseconds, you have to be pretty agile.  You'll need to re-think this, it is just not very usable.

Comment: From the doc (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx): "*The SendKeys class is susceptible to timing issues, which some developers have had to work around.*".

Comment: I see... So what can I do here to make this work? Or can I make something similar that works? I need something with a user input delay to work with... So is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Thank you, everyone, for helping!

I'm now using the GUI timer and it works flawlessly.